# Como criar um servidor apache na vivo internet?

Tags: apache, servidor

Como criar um servidor apache na vivo internet ?
Estou com problemas pois as portas de conexão estão bloqueadas na vivo internet e queria saber como conectar no apache de alguma forma ???

**EDIT:** somente 2 portas abertas : 51005 e 14330
a porta 51005 dá erro 401 não autorizado e a 14330 aparece a msg "not implemented" quando abre no navegador, alguem sabe o que fazer ?

Comment: Você deve estar tentando usar a porta 80, certo? As operadoras costumam bloquear a porta 80 pra saída nos planos comuns. Você terá que usar outra porta mesmo.

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50927/3635