# acesso externo com wamp

Tags: wamp

Queria saber como outras pessoas podem acessar meu webserver. Eu já liberei a porta 8080 e o icone esta verde. Também consigo acessar local com 192.168.0.10:8080 porém se eu usar o meu ip junto com :8080 não conecta. Alguém sabe?

Comment: Você pode usar [este site](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) para verificar se sua porta 8080 está aberta para conexões.

Comment: O Apache está configurado para receber conexões do seu IP? Ele precisa estar preparado para manipular requisições de domínio ou IP específico ou usar um coringa permitindo tudo. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Comment: A conexão 8080 está aberta sim. Port 8080 is open on 177.81.xx.xx. Eu coloquei o meu ip no listen e não deu certo.

Comment: @Asura Khan, eu costumo adicionar o executável. Ex: C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe . eu estou utilizando atualmente o Xampp acredito que no Wamp não mude muita coisa (Me refiro isso á uma rede local, caso seja o seu objetivo).

Comment: @adrianosymphony eu quero uma rede externa, que outras pessoas possam acessar o meu site através do meu ip:porta

Comment: @AsuraKhan se você tem um IP interno, provavelmente está usando um roteador. O IP externo portanto não é da sua máquina, e sim do roteador. Conforme a resposta dada, você pode dar um forward, ou se quiser apenas para testes, pode configurar **no roteador** uma DMZ apontando para o PC do servidor. Notar que o DMZ ("zona desmilitarizada") vai direcionar TODAS as portas para o seu PC, como se ele estivesse conectado diretamente à internet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O recomendável é você contratar um serviço profissional como uma *"hospedagem"* de sites profissional e fazer o upload via FTP ou SSH (ou SFTP) para a pasta `public_html` ou `www`, depende muito do servidor.

**Porém** se você realmente quer liberar o seu computador para acesso externo, talvez para poder trabalhar fora de casa, então segue:

1. Fixe o IP da sua máquina (para evitar mudanças de ip pelo DHCP)
2. Procure no seu roteador por VirtualServer (cada roteador é de uma maneira não tem como especificar)
3. Deve haver um local escrito "Foward", neste campo digite o seu ip fixado (no caso `192.168.0.10`)
4. Há provavelmente 3 ou 5 campos:

   - **Protocolo/Type:** Selecione TCP
   - **Port Start:** Digite 8080 (tanto no local quanto no `external`)
   - **Port End:** Digite 8080 (tanto no local quanto no `external`)
   - Na **Port Start** e **Port End** para `external` você pode colocar outra porta (geralmente 80 é bloqueada pelo ISP ou já vem configurada no roteador).
5. Reinicie o roteador (nem sempre é necessário)

> **Nota importante**, no caso usei por `8080` pode ser que ela também seja bloqueada, então você pode tentar outras portas como `9000`, `9001`, etc.

O IP de conexão de internet domestica geralmente é randômico, para saber o da sua ISP será necessário visitar algum site que informe isto, porém você pode "aplicar domínio" ao seu servidor domestico.

Você pode usar serviços como:

- [no-ip](http://www.noip.com/)
- [dynDns](http://www.dyn.com/) (pago)

Muitos roteadores tem o serviço de no-ip disponível (claro que precisa criar uma conta), porém muitas vezes o roteador é desatualizado e não funciona como esperado, neste caso o melhor é instalar o software do no-ip.

### Como configurar o no-ip:

1. Crie uma conta em https://www.noip.com/sign-up na parte de baixo do formulário clique no botão *Free Sign Up*.
2. Após confirmar a conta e se logar, você deve adicionar um host ou um domínio a sua conta, vá até Add Host:

   [image: Adicionar host ou dominio no no-ip]
3. Para adicionar um host para a sua conta, selecione o link "Add Host" a partir do menu "Hosts/Redirects":

   [image: Hostpage]
4. Escolha a opção *DNS Host A*
5. Selecione um HostName gratuito como `meusite.no-ip.biz`
6. Se pedir um serviço de email ("Choose Email Service"), selecione a opção **I don't need mail services at this time**, siga o exemplo da imagem:

[image: Desativar serviço de e-mail]

7. Agora algo muito importante, será necessário você instalar um software em sua máquina para resolver a questão do ip dinâmico:

   - Se estiver usando Windows baixe deste link: https://www.noip.com/download?page=win
   - Se estiver usando Linux baixe deste link: https://www.noip.com/download?page=linux
   - Se estiver usando Mac baixe deste link: https://www.noip.com/download?page=mac
8. Ao instalar o software ele irá pedir autenticação, é o mesmo da conta que você criou.
9. Após conectar-se através do software ele irá listar todos seus hosts (no caso só deve haver um), "cheque" o campo e após clique em "Refresh" (no software tem um botão para atualizar o IP).

Agora digite no navegador de web o nome de que você selecionou e porta que você liberou no roteador, deve ficar algo como:

```
http://meusite.no-ip.biz:8080
```

Se tiver usado outra porta como 9000 acesse:

```
http://meusite.no-ip.biz:9000
```

E assim por diante:

```
http://meusite.no-ip.biz:9001
http://meusite.no-ip.biz:9002
http://meusite.no-ip.biz:9003
```