# Executar um arquivo .EXE no Windows partindo de uma aplicação PHP em um servidor externo

Tags: php, windows, gammu

Estou com um Gateway de SMS (Gammu) devidamente instalado e funcionando em minha máquina local em casa.

Preciso que meu Script PHP hospedado em um servidor execute essa aplicação no meu servidor de SMS local. Como deveria proceder?

Preciso de aplicar algum tipo de permissão no Windows para tal? Como deverei passar o caminho para que o PHP tenha acesso a esse arquivo `.exe` ?

Answer (score 1):

O PHP sozinho não faz isso. O máximo que você vai conseguir é executar através do javascript:

```
<script>
function abrirArquivo() {
document.location.href = "C:/Program Files/caminho/arquivo.exe";
}
</script>
```

Dessa forma também abrirá uma caixa de diálogo perguntando se deseja executar o arquivo. Por questões de segurança não é possível abrir automaticamente. Pelo menos eu nunca via até agora.

Comment: A sua resposta pelo título da pergunta é considerada correta, mas acho que ele quer que execute um comando no Gammu como se fosse um "serviço".

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que possua um servidor na sua casa, aonde o Gammu deva estar rodando.

Por estar na sua casa o Gammu, e sua casa provavelmente utilizar um link doméstico com a internet, você tem um endereço de IP dinâmico na sua residência.

Portanto, em um primeiro lugar, é necessário registrar um DNS dinâmico apontando para a sua casa. Utilize um serviço como o No-Ip ou DynDNS. Você terá que instalar um programa no seu computador doméstico, de preferência no mesmo computador que o Gammu (já que provavelmente você não irá desligá-lo).

Feito isso, é necessário configurar o seu roteador para realizar direcionamento de portas para o computador com o Gammu. Veja na documentação do software que realiza a comunicação com o Gammu quais são as portas de rede utilizadas. Note que este aplicativo age como um servidor, recebendo comandos e os passando para que o Gammu execute. Se você não o possuir, precisará de um. Não conheço nenhum, por isso não vou recomendar, mas o Google cita alguns. Do contrário, construa o seu.

Existem classes que comunicam o PHP com o Gammu, mas o PHP precisa executar no mesmo computador que o Gammu esta. Portanto, uma solução seria instalar também um webserver no computador com o Gammu. No seu servidor na hospedagem, você enviaria comandos para o servidor do Gammu, e este por sua vez enviaria comandos para o Gammu.

Independete de utilizar um código de comunicação em PHP com o Gammu ou não, se fará necessário um aplicativo no seu servidor doméstico para fazer a interface entr o Gammu e seu webserver remoto, bem como as configurações no roteador e de IP dinâmico.

Comment: Para complementar a sua resposta, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635 , note que o exemplo é para o Apache, mas pode ser facilmente adaptado para outras softwares que suportam TCP (e em alguns casos UDP).