# PHP código não funciona

Tags: php

Eu estou tentando fazer um código que vai aparecer na tela da pagina "FEB ONLINE" quando o servidor estiver ligado, porém, está dando erro e também não mostra "FEB ONLINE" quando o servidor do jogo está online.

```
<?PHP 
$ts_ip = "177.82.148.141"; 
$ts_port = "2505"; 

$output = @fsockopen("$ts_ip", $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);  
stream_set_timeout($output, 00002);

if (!$output) { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>FEB Offline</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>FEB Online</B></FONT>"; 
} 
@fclose($output); 
?>
```

> Warning: stream_set_timeout() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /home/u918484727/public_html/teste.php on line 6

Comment: O erro é na linha anterior, o socket não está abrindo. Retire a `@` do código e deve aparecer o erro com o motivo real. Por favor atualize a pergunta com a mensagem de erro que aparecer.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function sockopen() in /home/u918484727/public_html/index.php on line 5

Comment: Parece que você removeu um `f` além da `@`.

Comment: Warning: stream_set_timeout() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u918484727/public_html/index.php on line 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta ler o erro `expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`, traduzindo seria:

> Era esperado que o parametro 1 fosse um resource, mas obteve um booleano

Ou seja `fsockopen` obteve `false` e como usou o `@` você não viu o erro, então ajuste para:

```
$output = fsockopen($ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

if (!$output) { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>FEB Offline</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>FEB Online</B></FONT>";
    fclose($output);
}
```

Recomendo que não use o arroba, em produção prefira ajustar o `display_errors` para `Off`, recomendo que leia isto:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)

Note que `$errno` e `$errstr` são [**referencias**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.php), nelas você poderá obter detalhes do erro na conexão, por exemplo:

```
$output = fsockopen($ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);

if (!$output) { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#DD0000><B>FEB Offline ($errstr - $errno)</B></FONT>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<FONT COLOR=#00DD00><B>FEB Online</B></FONT>";
    fclose($output);
}
```

Ou até customizar a mensagem, dependendo do erro.

### Timeout

Se obter um erro como:

> Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 177.82.148.141:2505 (Connection timed out)

É porque não conseguiu se conectar dentro do tempo determinado, no caso você usou 2 segundos:

```
$output = fsockopen($ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 2);
```

Tente ajustar para 10 segundos (creio que seja o ideal) ou mais:

```
$output = fsockopen($ts_ip, $ts_port, $errno, $errstr, 10);
```

Se não der tente um valor maior como 15 até 30, maior que 30 acho desnecessário, se usar 30 segundos e o erro ocorrer então o problema é no servidor, os motivos podem ser:

- Firewall
- Esta em uma rede fechada
- O endereço ou porta estão incorretos
- O servidor ao qual tentou acessar esta offline

### Liberar uma porta na internet

A porta que esta tentando liberar não foi "propagada" para internet, esta rodando apenas dentro da rede do computador, mas antes da internet você tem o roteador ou modem, tem que configurar eles para que possa liberar a porta na internet, como eu expliquei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635, você deve configurar o modem ou roteador (depende de como esta a rede), se for uma rede simples Wan+Lan, sem intermediários basta fazer isto:

> Se a rede for muito complexa, com muitas cascatas recomendo não fazer isto, procure um profissional na área de redes para que ele faça isto para você, pois mexer nisto pode dar muitas dores de cabeça

1. Fixe o IP da sua máquina/computador (para evitar mudanças de ip pelo DHCP)
2. Procure no seu roteador por `VirtualServer` (cada roteador é de uma maneira não tem como especificar)
3. Deve haver um local escrito **"Foward"**, neste campo digite o seu *IP local da sua máquina* e **não** o da internet fixado (por exemplo 192.168.0.10)
4. Há provavelmente 3 ou 5 campos:

   - **Protocolo/Type:** Selecione TCP (depende do tipo de servidor)
   - **Port Start:** Digite 2505 (tanto no `local` quanto no `external`)
   - **Port End:** Digite 2505 (tanto no `local` quanto no `external`)
   - Na **Port Start** e **Port End** para `external` você pode colocar outra porta (geralmente 80 é bloqueada pelo ISP ou já vem configurada no roteador).
     Reinicie o roteador (nem sempre é necessário)
5. Se o IP 177.82.148.141 for dinamico então recomendo usar o No-IP, detalhes em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58283/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-php-codigo-nao-funciona)