# Porta do roteador não abre!

Tags: apache

Então, eu estou com um problema aki. Queria fazer um website apache2 (apenas para teste) e liberá-lo para a rede, mas a porta do meu roteador não abre de jeito nenhum. Modelo do router: TL-WR740N e Modem: ZTE.
Obs: quando coloco o meu ip na porta 80 aparece uma janela dizendo "DSL Router", mas não consigo acessar a minha página (que configurei em outra porta).

Comment: Depende de quantas "camadas de rede**s**" você tem e também pode ser que o roteador bloquei a porta, pode ser também que o firewall esteja bloqueando, pode ser  o provedor de internet que tenha algum bloqueio, esta um pouco amplo para poder responder, veja se isto lhe ajuda: [acesso externo com wamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635)

Comment: o que seriam essas camadas? no roteador eu já abri, so se for o firewall ou o provedor (oi). Mas existe algum tipo de firewall no linux?como que acessa?

Comment: Jackson, coloquei entre aspas, digo camadas no caso um aparelho em Wan que esta entre o computador e o roteador ou modem (se o modem se conecta diretamente), então no caso teria que liberar a porta "camada" por "camada". Isto é apenas uma **teoria**, não tem como saber, por isso lhe informei todos possíveis problemas que presumo: 1. vc tem mais de um aparelho em Wan ("camadas") 2. Firewall que bloqueia algo 3. provedor que bloqueia algo. Claro que podem existir outros problemas, mas não tem como lhe dar uma resposta exata para isto, é muito relativo...

Comment: ... tente seguir as dicas do link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635 fazendo o passo a passo para ver se consegue, se ainda falhar tentarei lhe auxiliar via "chat" ;)

Comment: ok vou tentar, valeu pelas dicas : )

Answer (score 0):

1) Isso provavelmente é por causa do seu provedor de internet, você pode comunica-los para saber o que é preciso fazer para abrir as portas ou utilizar outra porta corrente do computador.

2) Voce pode utilizar uma VPN Open Port - Quando conectado a uma VPN Open Port você tem todas as portas necessárias abertas... Mas lembrando que VPN'S Open Port as gratuitas nem sempre são ilimitadas entao recomendo que você use o No-IP que dessa forma não haverá problema caso você use outra VPN

Espero ter Ajudado qualquer duvida só perguntar

Comment: Então tentei aqui e nada. Já desativei o firewall, coloquei meu IP na DMZ, será que o modem está de alguma forma "bloqueando" a conexão? testei aqui com a porta 7777 (para não haver conflito).

Answer (score -1):

1) Só usa um único modem?
Tenta usar DMZ ao invés de abrir uma porta no NAT. (é só pra testes mesmo não é?)
Desative o firewall pra garantir.

Se não funcionar, pode ser que seu provedor de internet não permita o uso da porta 80, tente com outra porta.

Comment: Sim, uso apenas um modem, mas será que interfere em algo o fato de eu usar um notebook (que está conectado por WiFi) e o modem (que está conectado a um computador)? Queria liberar as portas para o notebook

Comment: Pensei que tinha resolvido tudo, mas fui testar e na verdade o host só está na rede interna. Já coloquei no DMZ e nada, mas percebi que quando coloco o meu ip na porta 80 aparece uma janela dizendo "DSL Router", mas não consigo acessar a minha página (que configurei em outra porta).