# Como hospedar site no meu pc

Tags: servidor, xampp, redes, hospedagem

Estou criando uma aplicação em php com usando o xampp.
Gostaria de saber como faço para transformar meu PC em um servidor de hospedagem, para poder acessar minha aplicação de qualquer lugar.
Ja tentei acessar o admin do meu roteador (D-link Dir-608) criei um "servidor virtual", todavia, sem sucesso, ocorre erro ao tentar acessar o ip externo.
Alguém tem alguma dica ou tutorial ensinando? Obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [acesso externo com wamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50927/acesso-externo-com-wamp)

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o software **[No-IP](https://www.noip.com/pt-BR)**. Realize o cadastro no site, escolha um nome de host externo, exemplo **minha-casa.sytes.net**, instale o software em seu computador e acesse o software com suas credências.

Uma vez acessado e logado no software, será necessário configurar seu roteador para encaminhar um determinado tráfego a sua máquina. No caso de uma hospedagem, as portas importantes seriam as **80** para acesso via **HTTP**, e **443** para acesso via **HTTPS**. Acredito que apenas configurar a 80 seja o suficiente para o seu caso.

Para realizar essa configuração você vai precisar do IP da sua máquina, pois o que será feito é redirecionar todo o tráfego que **chegar na porta 80 do seu roteador para sua máquina**.

Para pegar seu IP, abra o Prompt de Comando e digite, **ipconfig**. Seu ip deverá ser algo parecido com 192.168.x.x, 10.x.x.x ou 172.16.x.x.

Acesse o roteador e procure pela configuração de encaminhamento de portas ou no inglês, port forward. Você deverá informar nessa configuração o endereço IP da sua máquina e também a porta de entrada e de saída. Tanto a porta de entrada como de saída será a porta 80 e o endereço IP o da sua máquina.

Com tudo configurado corretamente, você deverá configurar o xampp para responder no endereço do site que registrou no No-ip.

Espero que seja útil e consiga realizar sua configuração.

Comment: Só que a maioria dos ISP's bloqueiam a porta 80, justamente para evitar que as pessoas façam esse tipo de coisas em conexões caseiras, e se ler o contrato de grandes provedores, verá que criar um servidor web utilizando conexões caseiras viola o contrato e é passível de cancelamento do plano.

Comment: Na verdade minha intenção não é deixar hospedado na minha maquina, pretendo pagar um servidor dedicado, mas antes disso, preciso de um ambiente para realizar testes.

Comment: Bruno, fiz oque você sugeriu, mas quando tento acessar o host que o NO-IP forneceu, ocorre o seguinte erro:
Não é possível acessar esse site "..." demorou muito para responder.

Comment: Como nosso amigo acima citou, alguns ISP bloqueiam a porta 80, tente alterar para 81 e ver se consegue conectar. Se conseguir, é porque bloquearam a porta 80, se não, talvez algum passo esteja incorreto. Outro ponto a validar é, desative ou libere a porta correspondente no seu firewall (da sua máquina).

Comment: Coloquei o xampp na porta 888, desativei firewall e antivirus. consigo acessar o xampp através de "localhost:888" ele mostra a tela do dashboard. 
Quando coloco o host ou ip externo seguido de :888 ocorre o erro "demorou muito para responder."

Comment: Colocou também no roteador o forwarding da porta 888 para sua máquina?

Comment: Sim, fixei meu IP na maquina. E no roteador, configurei a porta 888 para o meu IP fixo.

Comment: @YagoLima tente o passo a passo da resposta que formulei https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635