# Como deixar um banco de dados mysql online?

Tags: mysql

Tenho um banco de dados em meu computador, porém preciso compartilhar ele com outras pessoas. Estou usando o banco de dados MySql, e preciso acessar esse banco de dados fora da rede, em outros dispositivos. Como deixar esse banco de dados online e compartilha-lo com demais pessoas ? Preciso compartilhar o banco de dados, pois outras aplicações vão acessa-lo. Como realizar ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro é necessário saber se o "IP externo" da rede do Windows Server é fixo ou não, sendo fixo basta saber o endereço, depois os próximos passos são:

1. Fixar o "IP local" do teu Windows Server (talvez este passo já esteja feito, pelo que entendi do teu site, já que o IIS já esta liberado)
2. Liberar porta do mysql que deve ser provavelmente a `3306` (padrão) no `VirtualServer` com o IP local da máquina, como descrevi em [**acesso externo com wamp**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50934/3635) (ignore a parte do no-ip se o teu IP for fixo)

   > É bom notar que este exemplo eu segui em um equipamento básico, sendo uma rede complexa o melhor é solicitar a liberação da porta `3306` para o(s) administrador(es) da rede
3. Se sua rede for simples depois de liberado VirtualServer > Forward, então basta tentar acessar de uma outra rede, como uma rede 3g ou 4g pelo `CMD` o comando:

   ```
   telnet x.x.x.x 3306
   ```

   Troque o `x.x.x.x` pelo IP externo que é usado na rede do Windows Server.
4. **Extra:** Se o teu IP não for fixo e a sua rede for simples/doméstica para que você consiga acessar o IIS e o mysql externamente será necessário configurar o no-ip, como descrito no link no "passo 2" (acima), então depois de liberado via no-ip basta testar a porta no cmd (usando uma rede 3g ou 4g), um exemplo fictício:

   ```
   telnet meusite.no-ip.biz 3306
   ```
5. **Extra:** Não tenho muitos detalhes da rede, os exemplos acima são para uma "rede simples", acaso a rede seja mais complexa **recomendo** que solicite ao administrador da rede que libere a porta pra ti, ele vai saber como fazer isto facilmente.

   **Então** se este for o caso, após o administrador confirmar que liberou a porta e você tiver um HOST válido (ou ip fixo do desta tal rede) bastará usar um destes dois (usando uma rede 3g ou 4g):

   Se for apenas o IP:

   ```
   telnet x.x.x.x 3306
   ```

   Se tiver um "hostname configurado":

   ```
   telnet meusite.com 3306
   ```